# Movie about man who kills two rival mob bosses to avenge his family

Tags: identify-this-movie

There is a city where all organised crime is run by one of two gangs. The two gang bosses each have a tall high-rise building, over the road from each other. Their penthouse suites face towards each other and they often glare across the road, trying to outsmart and out-plot each other.

Into this mix comes a young man. He starts at the bottom of the organisation and quickly works his way up the ranks. Unbeknownst to the bosses, he's actually working for both gangs at the same time, but he quickly becomes the right-hand-man in both. He offers ways to break the stalemate, finally defeating each mobster's nemesis.

However, the film ends with him in the office of one mafioso, with both bosses tied to chairs. We learn that actually his goal the whole time has been to avenge his family, killed by one or other of the gangs after his father got into gambling debt. He kills both gang bosses by taping plastic bags around their heads.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Lucky Number Slevin](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0425210/combined) from 2006 with Josh Hartnett, Bruce Willis and many others.

> A case of mistaken identity lands Slevin into the middle of a war being plotted by two of the city's most rival crime bosses: The Rabbi and The Boss. Slevin is under constant surveillance by relentless Detective Brikowski as well as the infamous assassin Goodkat and finds himself having to hatch his own ingenious plot to get them before they get him.

It's all there, including the ending. Here's the trailer: